# Did not find the metadata file netstandard2.0 dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, dependencies

What does it mean that visual studio did not find the metadata file netstandard2.0 dll? This file should will be on the bin folder so it should be automaticly created by xamarin by compiling the code.

[image]

Also it waring the depencences. Why is it? How could I solve this?

[image]

Comment: When you create the new project, have you got the same error? Did this project works before? When you have done when you get this error? Have you try to fix other errors before the errorr CS006?

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall visual studio... now I have other problems. Also I dalete the Mono.Android and nothing bad happened.

Comment: What is your other problems? And what does the nothing bad happened mean?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below to check if it is helpful to you.

1. Right click on the solution and click Properties.
2. Click Configuration on the left.
3. Make sure the check box under "Build" for the project is checked. If check then uncheck and check again and save the settings.
4. Clean the solution by right clicking on the project solution and rebuild the project again.
5. Make sure you don't have any other error messages in your project and if you do, fix those first.

I have got this solution from this link [Click here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac9ca792-cc8d-49a4-9e53-6d5dfcc1347c/error-cs0006-metadata-file-could-not-be-found?forum=csharpgeneral)

if this solution does not work for you please follow the steps below
1 - Close the solution
2 - Delete obj, bin folder for PCL, android, ios project
3 - Open solution and build

Comment: I already did all of these steps. Nothing works. Actually the last thing I tried was clear the nugets cache, this got worse it. Now not I have 709 errors... It seems to be losted the Xamarin.form dependency

Comment: Is your project new?؟

Comment: No, I have been working on it a few months

Comment: ok don't worry, follow the steps below 
1 - go to NuGet packages manager and make sure the xamarin.forms is already installed 
2 - if the xamarin.forms  already install remove it and reinstall again
3 - (optional) delete the bin and obj file 
4 - clean and rebuild the solution
i think these steps solve the last error 
* for the first error: If you do all the steps above in answer, please make sure you don't have any other error in the error list after build the app

Comment: Thank you but still not working. I reinstalled the xamarin.forms and now the Mono.Android is missing. I deleted the bin an obj files from the proyect and the proyect.Android and when I did the rebuild, the bin folder from the proyect folder didn't create. What it's happening here? haha I don't understand anything.

Comment: after building the app, What errors do you see??

Comment: The fist picture one "Did not find the metadata file netstandard2.0 dll"

Comment: I sure you have other error, please check again

Comment: Yes, there is an other error but I think it is a cause of the first one because those code lines have been working fine until I broke the app and suddenly the dll error showed and when I deleted the bin folder the proyect dll never rebuilld again... here is the video whit the compile and everthing https://vimeo.com/600870929

Comment: please try to comment on the error (login page > lin of code 17 ) and rebuild

Comment: if you need to close the app please use this code 
(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow(); ) , don't use this code (Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());)

Comment: Okay, now the dll error didn't show but still not creating the bin folder neither the dll. Now the recompile doesn't show any error and the solution and the android proyect compile but when I run it into a device nothing happens. The processes is omited

Comment: ok try to do that, close visual studio and delete the temp file and reopen vs

Comment: I did but same issue... the recompiler works but the running omitted and fail

Comment: if you use an emulator for test try to reopen it or change the emulator,